# how to create callback function using jquery

Tags: jquery, android, callback, cordova

I am new to jquery.
         In my phonegap android application,I want to create the callback function using jquery for automatically getting the alert when value from the server is inserted into the local database when the application is opened.Please tell me the solution.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you for some reason can't use the built in callbacks in jQuery you can create your own.

In it's simplest form it would look something like this:

```
function animateTop(element, callback) {
    $(element).animate({top: 100}, 1000, function() {
        callback.call();
    });
}
```

and you would use like so:

```
animateTop('#myelem', function() {
    alert('element was animated');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/LdDBn/1/

The example defeats the point a little, as it could be done easier by just using jQuery's built in callbacks, but it's just a realle simple example of how it's done, and the custom callback can be anything, not just a function, but if it is a function `typeof` should be used to check the callback type etc. There's plenty of tutorials on this stuff online.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried your code,but this function is called when the button is clicked.But i need to alert automatically without any click event.

Comment: Could you explain a little better, maybe post some code in your question so we can see what exactly you are trying to do.